# Live chat integration with webapp

Tags: chat, rest

I am exploring ways to integrate a live chat feature to a webapp. The webapp can be Java or .NET based. What are the options from open source or commercial space in order to  this?

I am looking for a simple text chat with unlimited agents and chats for B2B site. Not many features are required but basic reporting like response time, wait time, conversion and FAQ etc. The pricing side, would like to use if something available in OpenSource. Support feature required (even if paid).

Comment: Pure text chat for now with unlimited agents and chats. Should be easy on the pricing side. Standards canned reports like response times, wait time, conversion and FAQ